# A tool to analyze multidimensional tabular data

Tags: data-mining, tables

I have a bunch of data in the following format:

```
Count|| Fruit  |Fruit Col.|| Veget. |Veg.Col.|| Spice    
---------------------------------------------------------
 123 || Apple  | Red      || Carrot | Orange || Cumin   
  20 || Apple  | Red      || Carrot | Green  || Pepper  
... 20K more combinations...
   1 || Orange | Orange   || Potato | White  || Allspice
```

This is to be read as follows: ***Red apples*** in combination with **orange carrots** and **cumin** were encountered **123** times during the experiment.

I need to be able to answer at least following questions about the dataset:

- What are the most popular spices for the most popular vegetables among the most popular fruits, (a) with and (b) without the regard for the color of either?
- Which color of potatoes is encountered most often along with the most popular vegetable?
- What is the most popular red fruit that is encountered with green vegetable?

Etc.

"Most popular" here assumes answer like:

1. 5% Apple
2. 4% Orange
3. 1% Others

Please suggest a tool which will allow me to analyze my dataset in the way I described above.

Ideally the tool should *not* require me to write complicated code to ask the specific question (some coding beforehand is acceptable). A tool that will do what I need without coding would be perfect.

Comment: Any programming language should be able to do this. If you want a simple, general-purpose programming language, [Python](https://www.python.org/) is popular; if you want a statistical analysis specific programming language, your might try [R](http://www.r-project.org/). At any rate, there is nothing statistical here; this Q is off-topic for CV (see our [help center](http://stats.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)).

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about statistics.

Comment: Well, if the question is not about statistics (I have to believe you on that matter), please suggest a StackExchange site to ask it on. This question definitely is not about programming.

Comment: Outside of the programming angle, I don't know what SE site might be best. But you ask for a tool that would allow you to write code to solve these problems. I have already answered that. Any programming language will do. Moreover, I made two suggestions.

Comment: Sorry, but I do not ask for a tool that will allow me to write the code at all. I made a typo.

Comment: I fixed the question, sorry for misunderstanding.

Comment: @gung I believe most people would include the calculation and reporting of data summaries within the scope of statistics.

Comment: Hmm. I have two "close enough" answers in mind, and I am surprised why they haven't been suggested. Maybe there is another bug in my question text that confuses people?

Comment: I don't see how you can do what you want without coding. Your questions sound quite flexible, and can include logical multiple steps. It feels like Excel's Pivot Tables could answer some of your questions if you're willing to use a sticky note to keep track if intermediate results.

Answer (score 1):

Not to over simplify this but I reckon you could do everything you ask for using MS Excel. The 'SumIfs' feature allows you to count how many times sometime appears given certain criteria. Based on the data shown (and assuming I understand the question correctly), the question is: which spice is most commonly found with the vegetable most commonly found with a given fruit. So if apples are the most common fruit, and carrots are most commonly found with apples then you're asking what spice is found with the combination of apples and carrots.

So using excel you'd probably want to break it into a few steps:

1) Use SUMIF to calculate how many of each fruit is found.

2) Use SUMIFS to calculate how many of each vegetable is found with each fruit (making a table with fruit in rows and veg in columns for example)

3) Finally an even longer SUMIFS formula to find add all the counts for all the spices for each fruit and veg (can't really make a single table for this as it would need to be a 3D array but you could make multiple tables if you require all the data as opposed to selecting the values based on the previous table).

Finally if you want answers in percentages of the total then you can simply SUM the 'count' column, divide all answers by this number and then multiply by 100! This should require no coding at all, just an easy to read layout in excel and 3 or 4 formulas. Please ask if anything here is ambiguous.

SUMIFS: http://office.microsoft.com/en-gb/excel-help/sumifs-function-HA010047504.aspx

Comment: Thanks, this could work. A demo table would help though.

Comment: Well, in that case I have to deem using `SUMIFS` as a programming. That is, user has to think rather hard and do fiddly work to get a report for the next question from the report.

Comment: @AlexanderGladysh Have you tried using SUMIFS to get the answer you required? What was the result? I had a go myself and it seemed to work fine. Try and get a table with fruit on the rows and spices on the columns and the total count in the cells. Once you've got that it should be easy!

Comment: The point is that there is a multitude of questions, that may be asked by user (i.e. not a person who configured the initial report). This is the reason behind the no-programming requirement.

Comment: Not at all. You can simply set up the sum if, and have them based on the value in a cell. If you change the value of that cell then the results will change to reflect that.

Comment: This will answer for one question, for example: "What are the most popular spices for the most popular vegetables among the most popular fruits, (a) with and (b) without the regard for the color of either?" For the next question ("Which color of potatoes is encountered most often along with the most popular vegetable?") I have to redo the report from scratch — unless I miss something.

Comment: Yeah. You will need 2 cells for the answers: one for with and one for without regard of color. But the SUMIFS equations will be very similar. They can be based on the values held in 3 cells, one for the question fruit, one for the question veg and one for the question spice

Comment: Still, this is requires more flexibility of the mind from the user than I can afford :)

Comment: I can't help but feel you want a table written up for you. I'm pretty sure that's against the rules since you haven't tried it yourself yet. :/